# Remote Data binding to kendo ui grid taking more time in IE 11

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am binding remote data to kendo ui grid using angular 1.4. Grid is  having 66 columns and page size is 50.

My kendo JS file version 2016.3.1118.

It is taking around 15 to 20 sec to bind the data.

any solution to reduce to time.

Comment: Add your relevant code as well to question. Info is not enough.

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/4aa2d3bd23ecb6287d65a5e08bbc5fe5.html

Comment: added file loaction can you please go and check in above link